# Angular Routing: Passing dynamic url data to components

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':product/new',
        children: [{
            path: 'std/:country',
            component: SignUpComponent,
            data: {
                animation: 'animate',
                segment: 'std',
                country: ':country'
            }
        }, {
            path: 'exp/:country',
            component: PaymentComponent,
            data: {
                animation: 'animate',
                segment: 'exp'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Is `country: ':country'` the right way of passing dynamic url data to the `SignUpComponent`? If yes, How can I consume this data in my `SignUpComponent Component`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor

```
public constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) {
      console.log(route.snapshot.data['country']);
  }
```

Or you can use the following as per documentation from the router outlet ([check here](https://angular.io/guide/router))

```
export class AppComponent {
  getCountryData(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['country'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the country property in the data object. The country info in the url should be enough.

To retrieve the country parameter from the route :

```
class  SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
        // params.country should be defined here    
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-gsp7da?embed=1&file=app/views/home/home.component.ts) // click on Home

`import {  ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';`

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  alert(route.snapshot["data"].country)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pass this way `country: ':country'`. 
By using this way you can read path variables

```
import {  ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  alert(route.snapshot["data"].country)
}
```